# Jython, wrong number of expected arguments

Tags: java, jython, graphics2d

I'm writing a graphics app in Jython 2.7, and am doing something fundamentally wrong. I've stripped out most of the code for this question, and with the following code I get "TypeError: setColor(): expected 2 args; got 1".

```
from java.awt import Color
from java.awt import Graphics2D

class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.g=Graphics2D
 
    def drawLine(self):
        self.g.setColor(Color.black)

d=test() 
d.drawLine()
```

I know this has something to do with how Java methods work in Jython, and I just need some direction.

I tried java "getColor" to store the color in a variable and then passing that to setColor, but I had the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot a pair of parenthesis: `Graphics2D()`

Comment: If I add the parenthesis, I get another error: "TypeError: No visible constructors for class (java.awt.Graphics2D)"

Comment: Ok, the error I got after adding parenthesis exposed another flaw in my program.  I modified the code so the graphics was added to a canvas, and the canvas was added to a container, and now I can import the whole thing into my GUI as an object. Perfect! Thank you Sören!